How to use a string function for a report to select only some characters for the group row or column
For a report I want use a string function to only select the two characters of a column: product_group = substr(external_id,4,2).

For some reports in the middle substr(external_id,4,2),
For others the first two substr(external_id,0,2)

In SQL this would look like this:
SELECT substr(external_id, 1, 2) AS prefix, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users
GROUP BY prefix;

This example returns this result



prefix
count




AB
3


AC
2


AD
1



This is a preview of a similar report

But in my case I want to use the prefix either as row group



Year
prefix
count




2024
AB
30



AC
0



AD
10


2023
AB
27



AC
4



AD
2



Or as a column



Year
AB
AC
AD




2024
30
0
10


2023
27
4
2



How can this be achieved in salesforce report?

You can add a row-level formula give it a name (for example MyRowLevelFormular) and use this formula:
MID(external_id, 1, 2)

Like this

Then move it to the group rows section (for details see row-level formula documentation)

Everthing worked as expected. Thanks for the help.
